# How to run an application as a system service?

Tags: macos, services, launch-services, plex

I'd like to be able to run Plex media server in the background even when not logged on. This is something I could easily setup in Windows but I can't figure out if this is possible in OSX.

Comment: This is a pretty common question but there is no straightforward answer. There is a plist [here](https://forums.plex.tv/index.php/topic/121218-i-really-need-the-ability-to-launch-plex-media-server-on-boot-up/?p=729946) that you can try to use.

Comment: You may find it easier to set up Plex in a separate user account, enabling the Run at Login option, and set the Mac to always log that account in at system boot. Then, you (or any other users of the computer) would simply log into your personal accounts as normal, and PMS would continue running in the background.